# How many inventions did Fred and George have?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-items

Fred and George Weasley are known for their trouble-making and general "solemnly swearing they are up to no good". Their antics/adventures give something to smile about and show us not all wizards are as serious as Professor McGonagall and Hermione. This gives them a reputation of being less intelligent and indeed they only achieved three OWLs.

However, we also see the twins have quite a brilliant side! Being able to open and successfully run a shop in Diagon Alley without having completed their Hogwarts education is no easy take (IMO, anyway). Their creations helped students get out of class, our heroes out of tight spot, and even stop our enemies execute an evil plot.

Ginny may have said it best:

> "We’ve been hearing explosions out of their room for ages, but we never
> thought they were actually making things," said Ginny. "We thought
> they just liked the noise."
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

**Do we know how many *things* Fred and George invented?**

Comment: Just for the record, I don't think there's any evidence that the twins had a reputation for being less than intelligent. On the contrary, doesn't Hermione herself say flat out at one point that they are highly intelligent? (Or is it just Mrs Weasley?)

Comment: Do you mean joke items or jokes?

Comment: @Obie2.0 Joke items, i couldnt think of otherwise to specify it by name, if you have something better in mind please feel free to edit :)

Comment: There is a list [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Weasleys%27_Wizard_Wheezes). I'm a bit too tired to find quotes for all of them though.

Comment: https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/37FeGqjnK8Aou0gYWeQMw8/8464e58de1cb333c65f27966bd6a153b/Fred_and_George__Troublemakers_in_Chief.jpg

Comment: @ibid this of their pranks they made to other people, the question is about the jokes that they created, those for example that they well selling at their store....

Comment: @hedgehog - It has both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Fred and George sell the following items of their own invention in their shop](https://www.pottermore.com/features/fred-and-george-weasley-troublemakers-in-chief-infographic):

1. **Extendable Ears** - Long, flesh-coloured pieces of string which one can insert in one's ear, then shove the other end under (for example) a door, and one will hear the conversation or other noise. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

   > Ron: "Fred and George have invented Extendable Ears, see. They're
   >   really useful."
   >
   > Harry: "Extendable-?"
   >
   > Ron: "Ears, yeah. Only we've had
   >   to stop using them lately because Mum found out and went berserk."
2. **Self-Inking, Spell-Checking, and Smart-Answer Quills** - first appearance *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*
3. **Skiving Snackboxes (includes: Puking Pastilles, Fainting Fancies, Fever Fudge, and Nosebleed Nougat)** - The user develops strange symptoms depending on the type of sweet eaten. The purpose of these were to make a student appear unable to stay in class. Most came in two colour-coded parts: one that would cause the malady, and one that would cure the pupil once they had left class. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

   > Hermione: "It is NOT excellent!"
   >
   > Fred: "Course it is, they're alive,
   >   aren't they?"
   >
   > Hermione: "You can't do this, what if you made one of
   >   them really ill?"
   >
   > Fred: "We're not going to make them ill, we've
   >   already tested them all on ourselves, this is just to see if everyone
   >   reacts the same —"
4. **Canary Creams** - They have the appearance and taste of ordinary custard creams, but when eaten, they transfigure the eater into a large canary. Within a minute, the person will molt his or her feathers and revert to normal. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*.

   > "Want a jam tart, Hermione? It’s all right. I haven’t done anything to
   >   them. It’s the custard creams you’ve got to watch..." - Fred Weasley
5. **Headless Hats** - Small hats covered in pink feathers. When worn, the hat and head of the person wearing it, disappears. First appearnace in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*.

   > "How do those hats work then? I mean, obviously it's some kind of
   >   Invisibility Spell, but it's rather clever to have extended the field
   >   of invisibility beyond the boundaries of the charmed object..." - Hermione Granger
6. **Wildfire Whiz-bangs** - Unstoppable fireworks that are charmed to explode when struck with a Stunning Spell, and to multiply by ten when hit with a Vanishing Charm. They include shocking-pink Catherine wheels, fire-breathing dragons, sparklers that spell out profanity, rockets with long tails of silver stars and firecrackers. When any two types collide, they make new kinds such as flying silver and pink pigs. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*.

   > Hermione: "They were wonderful fireworks."
   >
   > George: "Thanks. Weasleys' Wildfire Whiz-bangs. Only thing is, we used our whole stock; we’re going to have to start again from scratch now."
   >
   > Fred: "It was worth
   >   it, though.
7. **Ton-Tongue Toffee** -  a rainbow colored sweet with the power of the Engorgement Charm, makes the tongue of the consumer swell to an indeterminate size. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

   > George Weasley: "How big did his tongue get?"
   >
   > Arthur Weasley: "It was four feet long before his parents would let me shrink it."— after Dudley Dursley ate the toffe
8. **Trick Wands** -  When used to cast a spell, they turn into random objects (e.g. rubber chickens). A more expensive version beats the user around the head and neck. First appearance *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
9. **Patented Daydream Charms** - Virtually undetectable, they produce a very realistic daydream lasting for thirty minutes. Side effects may include drooling and/or dazed expression. First appearance in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*
10. **Punching telescopes** - When it is squeezed, a tiny fist on a spring erupts from its end and lands a punch, accompanied by a puff of black smoke and a loud bang.[1](https://www.pottermore.com/features/fred-and-george-weasley-troublemakers-in-chief-infographic) The purple bruise caused by the telescope does not fade by itself, and cannot be healed with standard remedies. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.

    > Fred: "And what's happened to your eye, Hermione?"
    >
    > Hermione: "Your punching telescope."
    >
    > Fred: "Oh, blimey, I forgot about those. Here... Just dab it on, that bruise'll >be gone within the hour. We had to find a decent bruise remover. We're testing most of our products on ourselves."
11. **Guaranteed Ten-Second Pimple Vanisher** - Comes in a small pink pot and is excellent on anything from boils to pimples and to blackheads. Its purpose is to immediately eliminate extreme face acne. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.
12. **WonderWitch love potions** - A range of Love Potions that induce infatuation in the drinker for up to twenty-four hours, depending on the weight of the boy and attractiveness of the girl in question. Known potions in this range included: Beguiling Bubbles, Cupid Crystals, Heartbreak Teardrops, Kissing Concoction, Twilight Moonbeams, Calamity Lotion, Crush Blush, Love is Blind Eye Serum, Flirting Fancies
13. **Reusable Hangman** - Consisted of a small, wooden man which climbed the stairs leading to a set of gallows with every letter missed. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.
14. **Shield Gloves, Hats, and Cloaks**
15. **Pygmy Puffs** - miniature Puffskein, bred in the back of the shop. First appearance in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.
16. **U-No-Poo** -  Causes constipation in the unknowing taker. The pills can be mashed up and mixed with food or drink. First appearance in *Harry Potter and The Half Blood Prince*.

    > WHY ARE YOU WORRYING ABOUT YOU-KNOW-WHO? YOU SHOULD BE WORRYING ABOUT
    >   U-NO-POO THE CONSTIPATION SENSATION THAT'S GRIPPING THE NATION!"
    >   —Advertisement poster in the window of Weasleys' Wizard Wheezes
17. **Edible Dark Marks** - sweets that were shaped like the Dark Mark. First seen in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*
18. <s>Peruvian Instant Darkness Powder</s> (was imported from Peru, as name suggests)
19. **Decoy Detonators** - black horn-like objects designed to create a diversion. After being dropped, the decoy runs a fair distance away, makes a noise like a loud bang, and releases clouds of black smoke, diverting attention from the user. - First appearance in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure they didn't invent Peruvian Instant Darkness Powder.

Comment: And the WonderWitch potions are presumably copyright to WonderWitch.

Comment: Did they invent that swamp in Order of the Phoenix. And also the fireworks.

Comment: They didn't invent the concept of trick wands - Ludo Bagman says that it's (one of?) the best he's seen, implying that there are others available before the Weasleys made theirs - so I'm not sure if they can really be credited with anything there. They may have perfected the concept, but that doesn't make it their invention.

Comment: @Richard Is WonderWitch mentioned at any point before - or after - the scene in their shop in HBP, though? Hard to tell if WonderWitch is its own brand owned by somebody else that they're reselling or a trademark of the Weasleys that they use for branding all of their witch-centred merchandise. That aside, not sure I'm convinced that love potions count, since we know those definitely existed before the Weasley twins were born.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Interestingly, the designers who made the labels indicated that WonderWitch was "[Since 1952](http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-mqaii0/products/861/images/4556/WONDER_WITCH_Product__68891.1451918110.1280.1280.jpg?c=2)". Obviously this conflicts with the idea that its a Weasley-invented product range. That doesn't mean that they didn't buy a existing brand and restock it with their own products...

Comment: @Richard 1) Darkness powder was imported, fixed that. 2) WonderWitch is the boys in house name for products geared more for witches, the 1952 label was an error.

Comment: @Skooba - Well, the wiki says it was an error. That doesn't mean it *was* an error, just that the person who wrote the wiki article thinks that it is.

Comment: @Richard Where are those labels from? Any reason to consider them canon?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - My understanding is that these are the labels that were used in the film, but since they were unreadable in the film, your canon mileage may vary.